# {} + {}. Почему такой результат?

Tags: javascript

`{} + {}
"[object Object][object Object]"`

В статье [Преобразование объектов: toString и valueOf](https://learn.javascript.ru/object-conversion) в разделе [Итоги](https://learn.javascript.ru/object-conversion#%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE) описывается поведение объекта( `{}` ) в основном потоке кода, но в консоли поведение отличается. Я даже где - то видел подобный пример: `{} + {}`. Там говорилось, что левый операнд считается как пустой "блок кода", а правый приводиться к числу, результатом который будет `NaN`.

За одно хотел спросить, как видит парсер это пример: `{} - {}`.

1. Парсер игнорирует левый объект и воспринимает его как "блок кода". Тогда возникает вопрос, почему в примере выше происходит конкатенация?
2. Он их приводит к числу(NaN) и вычитает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S: Знал бы английский и умел бы хорошо понимать документация ECMAScript, я бы не спрашивал.

Comment: Это где это у вас так получилось? В моём Firefox `{} + {}` даёт именно `NaN`

Comment: @andreymal http://joxi.ru/BA0OWRvHB7Jo52

Comment: А у меня вот так https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3xQw.png :)

Comment: @andreymal я и в опере тестил. скрин залил, там вообще ересь.

Comment: Опера опере рознь https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSz4B.png :D

Comment: @andreymal может внедряют новые фишки ECMAScript, и не все пофикси. просто у Crome есть разные версии браузера, а это стабильная и в ней такая шляпа как и в Opera.

Comment: Это же классический WAT :https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: @PashaPash, а вопрос в том, что в хроме сделали с консолью, что раюоьает иначе))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Основной поток кода - это место, которое не является частью выражения.

Вот моменты языка, которые могут быть размещены только в основном потоке кода:

- function declaration (отличается от function expression)
- блок кода (отличается от объекта)
- метки (отличаются от имён свойств)
- все синтаксические конструкции языка: if, else, try, var и т. д.

Если есть две похожие конструкции, одна из которых может существовать только в основном потоке, то именно этот критерий будет использоваться для их различения: если код размещён в основном потоке кода, то выбирается соответствующая конструкция, а если в выражении, то другая.

Что касается записи `{}+{}`, то в случае основного потока кода её значение обычно вообще никуда не попадает, хотя и выводится в REPL-средах как результат. Первая фигурная скобка означает открытие блока кода, затем вторая его заканчивает. Потом попадается плюс - левого операнда у нас нет, значит он унарный. Мы уже находимся в выражении. Фигурная скобка в выражении начинает объект. Следующая - заканчивает объект. Получается `+{}`, затем `+"[object Object]"` и `NaN`.

В случае же с `console.log` сам вызов функции образует выражение. Поэтому первая пара скобок превращается в объект, а вся сумма после приведения типов в конкатенацию строк.

Единственный способ (по крайней мере в ES2018-) получить в коде это передать строку с кодом в eval.

```js
function run(code) {
  try {
    console.log(eval(code))
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e.name + " " + e.message)
  }
}

run('{console.log("I am the code block")} + {i:0, am:1, an:2, object:3}')
run('({a:0, pair:1} + {of:2, objects:3})') // круглые скобки
run('{not_object:0} + {object:1}') // метка!
run('{not_object:0, really_not:1} + {object:2}') // ошибка - метка не может быть вне основного потока
run('{not_object:0; really_not:1} + {object:1}') // `;`, а не `,` - две метки
```

Что касается консоли хрома - судя по всему они сделали умное определение, является ли нечто в фигурных скобках объектом или куском кода. Причём, предпочтение отдаётся объекту. Думаю, это сделано для большего удобства, что если ты вводишь выражение в консоль, то ты хочешь результат выражения, который ты не получишь в основном потоке кода. Но стоит заметить, что эта штука в консоли работает только для top-level-кода (да и то не всегда), и не распространяется на вложенный код:

[image: скриншот консоли хрома]

А логика угадывания не такая уж сложная: если код начинается на `{` и заканчивается на `}`, не являющуюся частью однострочного комментария, то он в первую очередь пытается распарсить его как выражение, а если не получается, то как statement:

[image: скриншот ещё нескольких примеров]

Comment: исправьте строчку `...то авыбирается соответствующая конструкция, а если в выражении, то другая.`. Если я вас правильно понял, то что вывела консоль, сделано для удобства, ибо в основном потоке кода это `пустой блок когда`. Еще хотел спросить по поводу комментария: `{not_object: 0} // Комментарий`, и помещения `{not_object:0}` в `{}`. К примеру оператор `()` группирует выражение и `{} + {}` станет выражением (прошу прощение за тавтологию), а `{}` по идеи аналогичен обычному потоку кода, и работает так же, но диссонанс в том, что сам поток кода работает по другому `типо для удобства`))

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный, предполагаю, что логика примерно такая: комментарий расцениевается как форсирование statement вместо expression, поскольку комментарий не является частью expression'а. Круглые скобки явно указывают на expression, а фигурные - это просто блок кода. Их фишка с выражением работает только на одном уровне - верхнем - как только появляется вложенность, идёт парсинг по нормальным правилам.

Comment: Основную суть уловил, но мои знания работы парсера скудны, как и работа блока кода. буду вам признателен, если вы загляните на мой вопрос и поможете мне на него ответить. [Вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/737285/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8#comment1124401_737285)

Comment: P.S: Если не сложно, то можете более простым языком или перефразировать ваш комментарий:  `Их фишка с выражением работает только на одном уровне - верхнем - как только появляется вложенность, идёт парсинг по нормальным правилам.`

Comment: top-level-код - это код, расположенный вне любых функций или блоков кода непосредственно в скрипте. В принципе, то же можно сказать и про консоль (хотя там несколько другая ситуация, но ты ведь сам никаких обёрток не пишешь). Судя по всему, они предположили, что либо пользователь ввёл некий expression, либо кусок кода. И если есть причины считать, что это не expression (комментарий), либо пользователь явно начал блок кода, то всё идёт по правилам js. А если похоже на expression, то так и вычислить, как если бы он присваивал результат в переменную.

Answer (score -1):

Приведение.
Если может к числам приводит к числам.

Если не может то приводит к строке, {} + {}, вызывает приведение к строке, конкатенация 2-х строк.

При вычитании считается что оба операнда числа, преобразование не происходит возвращается NaN

Comment: Во-первых, частично неверно. А во-вторых, вопрос не об этом.

Comment: очень аргументировано конечно