# Почему такое отображение в консоли?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, консоль

1: Создал объект через конструктор и заменил свойство `constructor` в прототипе.

[image: Img]

```js
function Test(){
  this.test = 0;
}

function One(){
  this.one = 1;
}

function Two(){
  this.two = 2;
}

One.prototype.constructor = Test;

var a = new One;

console.log(a);
```

Имя объекта по прежнему наследуется от конструктора `One`. А теперь кое что изменим.

2: Теперь мы переменную `a` поместим в свойство `prototype` другому конструктору.

[image: Img 2]

```js
function Test(){
  this.test = 0;
}

function One(){
  this.one = 1;
}

function Two(){
  this.two = 2;
}

One.prototype.constructor = Test;

var a = new One;

Two.prototype = a;

console.log(a);
```

Здесь видно что имя объекта поменялась на конструктор `Test` в свойстве `constructor`, который находиться в прототипе.

3: Еще я заметил, что если создать объект через конструктор в прототип объекта, то он будет менять свое имя относительно своего свойства `constructor`, но если создать просто как объект в переменную, то почему - то свойства `constructor` в его прототипе ни как на него не повлияет (самый первый пример этому свидетельствует).

[image: Img3]

```js
function Test(){
  this.test = 0;
}

function One(){
  this.one = 1;
}

function Two(){
  this.two = 2;
}

function Three(){
  this.three = 3;
}

function Four(){
  this.Four = 3;
}

One.prototype = new Test;

var a = new One;

a.__proto__.__proto__.constructor = Two;

console.log(a.__proto__.__proto__ == Test.prototype);

console.log(a);
```

P.S: 
1: Заметил закономерность, что как только объект созданный через конструктор становиться чьим - то прототипом, то его имя будет меняться относительно его свойства `constructor` в прототипе.

[image: Img2]

Как только мы объект созданный через конструктор поместили в чей - то прототип, то имя объекта в переменной сразу же начало меняться.

2: В это примере оно меняется сразу, ибо создан в прототип другого объекта.

[image: Img3]

Резюмирую: Это может быть багом консоли или я что - то не понимаю?

Update: Когда я во втором пункте переменную `a` поместил в свойство `prototype` другого конструктора, то потом у нее начало изменяться имя относительно свойства `constructor`, но я заметил что это относиться только к этой переменной ибо если создать еще один объект на основе этого же конструктора и не присваивать ее в прототип, то она не будет менять имени относительно свойства `constructor`. Этот пример наглядно покажет суть.

[image: Img4]

```js
function Test() {
  this.test = 0;
}

function One() {
  this.one = 1;
}

One.prototype.constructor = Test;

var a = new One;

var aa = new One;

var aaa = Object.create(a);

console.log(a);
console.log(aa);
console.log(aaa);
```

Comment: добавь твой код кодом

Comment: @Grundy добавил.

Comment: Вас, что смущает? что в последнем результате вместо Test в конструкторе выводится two?

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный, предлагаю задать этот вопрос дополнительно на enSO

Comment: @Grundy я только за, но с английским трабл. Если кто нибудь это реализует, то я буду благодарен и думаю будем очень познавательно.

Comment: Не воспроизводится (хром 61.0.3163.100, x64)

Comment: Хром 62.0.3202.89, x64 - тоже не воспроизводится

Comment: Чем важно имя, которое выдаёт консоль, она его может по астрологическому прогнозу выдавать, и что из того, если это название не имеет значения в коде? Предполагаю что дело в следующем: классы и функции в JS неразделимы. Но задача консоли - это сделать понятнее то, что её просят залоггировать. И конкретно в вашей версии браузера - при отладке ищутся конструкции вида: `y.prototype = new x();` , это считается наследованием, где `x` класс-предок `y` с соответствующими модификациями вывода в консоль данных переменных.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/765445/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-proto-%D0%BE%D1%82-prototype/765455#765455

Answer (score 1):

достаточно сложно дать простой ответ на твой вопрос.
Могу посоветовать посмотреть выступление Андрея Мелихова с HolyJS 2017 года, он касается этой темы - ["Hidden Classes"](https://youtu.be/SNs61SwZbTI?t=504), если в кратце - то так работает движок V8.

Answer (score -1):

Опыт подсказывает следующие вещи, если смотреть глазами разработчиков интерпретатора.

1. Прототип используется для поиска свойств не найденных в головном объекте.
   Присвоение конструктора объекту "прототип" объекта имеющего свой конструктор не имеет смысла. Объект сохранит первичный конструктор.
2. Видимо в таком случае при присвоение прототипа происходит перебор свойств, ищется свойство "constructor", имя конструктора прототипа затирает оригинальное имя.

Answer (score -2):

Этот код создает прослойку, точнее создает новый объект test в прототип

```
One.prototype = new Test
```

То есть он идет в объект One ищет свойство proto и закидывает конструктор теста туда. Точнее создает еще одно **proto** Ключевое слово тут New.

```
One.prototype = a;
```

Код который выше, он просто ищет свойство и запихивает туда прототип а.

Подводим итоги. В первом случае мы создаем прослойку объекта. Для чего нужно? приведу практический пример.
У нас есть три объекта, скажем Animal, Fish,  Lion. Animal будет объектом, от которого последние два будут наследоваться. То есть все функции прототипа Animal будут известны и Fish и Lion (к примеру eating, sleeping), но у Fish есть отличие она(рыба) умеет плавать, а объект Lion(лев) бегать. Соответственно, код будет выглядеть следующим:

```
Lion.prototype = new Animal;
Lion.prototype.run = function() {
     // Lion running here
}
Fish.prototype = new Animal;
Fish.prototype.swimming = function() {
     // Fish swimming here
}
```

Если бы мы написал так

```
Lion.prototype = Animal;
Fish.prototype = Animal;
```

То и львы, и рыбы бегали и плавали.

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/class-inheritance

Comment: 1. Последний кусок кода вообще неверный - это не наследование, т. к. методы предка исчезнут - надо бы исправить. 2. Пример наследования с `new Animal` совсем не лучший. 3. А как это вообще относится к вопросу?

Answer (score -2):

При создании объекта функции, вместе с ней создаётся пустой объект под прототип.
В функцию пишется ссылка на него в свойство `prototype`.
А в него ссылка на функцию - в `constructor`.

Если расширять прототип через `F.prototype.method=...` все цепочки constructor-prototype остаются целыми.

Если же заменять прототип целиком `F.prototype = new Two()`, то желательно правильно восстановить в нём свойство `constructor`.
Иначе цепочка нарушена и консоль в своём поиске уходит непонятно куда.

**UPDATE**

Если взять node.js, то там всё чётко:

```
function One() {};
function Two() {};
Two.prototype = new One();

var a = new Two();
console.log(a); // One {}
```

Так как `a.constructor` через все цепочки прототипов ссылается на `One()`.
Если правильно восстановить ссылку на конструктор, то всё становится, как надо:

```
Two.prototype.constructor = Two;
console.log(a); // Two {}
```

Либо можно хоть так:

```
a.constructor = function Three() {};
console.log(a); // Three { constructor: [Function: Three] }
```

Другой вопрос, почему Chrome сначала указывает на `Two`.
Видимо просто берёт название используемой функции и не напрягается для оптимизации.
Когда же объект начинает влиять на цепочку прототипов, то здесь уже проходит по цепочке и выставляет "нормальные" имена.

Пример можно сократить до:

```
> new Two();
--> Two {}
> F.prototype = new Two();
--> One {}
```

Comment: Это хоть как-то с вопросм связано?

Comment: @Qwertiy, да это прямой и исчерпывающий ответ на поставленный вопрос.

Comment: @vasa_c не вижу объяснений почему после изменения прототипа Two у объекта a меняется отображение (см. пример 2 в вопросе)

Comment: @PavelMayorov вряд ли где-то можно получить официальные объяснения, только в коде хромиума разбираться. Предположение же моё в последнем абзаце - кэш и его сброс при изменении цепочки прототипов.