# В чем отличие __proto__ от prototype?

Tags: javascript, прототипное-наследование

В чем различие этих 2 способов прототипного наследования и какой из них более правильнее использовать?

```js
function Cat() {
    this.__proto__.type = 'кот';
}


var cat = new Cat();
console.log(cat.type); // кот


function CatTwo() {
}
CatTwo.prototype.type = 'тоже кот';

var catTwo = new Cat();
console.log(catTwo.type); // тоже кот
```

Comment: http://learn.javascript.ru/new-prototype

Answer (score 7, accepted):

На самом деле в примере в вопросе нет наследования.

---

`__proto__` до недавнего времени не был стандартизирован.

В последних спецификациях можно найти, что [getter `__proto__`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-get-object.prototype.__proto__), обертка над вызовом внутренней функции `[[GetPrototypeOf]]`.

Точно такая же, как и [функция Object.getPrototypeOf](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-object.getprototypeof)

---

Если применительно к приведенному коду:

в первом случае значение прототипа меняется каждый раз при создании объекта, во втором - устанавливается всего один раз.

Отсюда можно сделать вывод, что если есть доступ к конструктору, прототип лучше менять непосредственное у него.

---

Пример, когда приведенный код выдаст разные значения:

```js
function Cat(type) {
  this.__proto__.type = type;
}

var cat = new Cat('кот');
console.log(cat.type); // кот
var cat2 = new Cat('кот2');
console.log(cat.type); // кот2
console.log(cat2.type); // кот2


function CatTwo() {}
CatTwo.prototype.type = 'тоже кот';

var catTwo = new CatTwo();
console.log(catTwo.type); // тоже кот
```

Answer (score 5):

**Свойство __proto__**

Абсолютно любой объект в JavaScript имеет свойство **proto**. Это скрытое системное свойство, и не во всех реализациях языка оно доступно пользователю.

При обращении к любому свойству объекта, оно в первую очередь ищется в самом объекте:

```
var obj = {ownProperty: 1};
console.log(obj.ownProperty);// 1
```

Но если его там нет, поиск происходит в свойстве **proto**:

```
obj.__proto__ = {propertyOfProto: 2};
console.log(obj.propertyOfProto);// 2
```

Если его нет и там, оно ищется дальше по цепочке:

```
obj.__proto__.__proto__ = {propertyOfProtosProto: 3};
console.log(obj.propertyOfProtosProto);// 3
```

Эта цепочка называется цепочкой прототипов (prototype chain).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**proto** любого значения (кроме null и undefined) ссылается на prototype соответствующего ему типу данных:

```
(0).__proto__ === Number.prototype
false.__proto__ === Boolean.prototype
"string".__proto__ === String.prototype
(new Date).__proto__ === Date.prototype
(function(){}/* new Function */).__proto__ === Function.prototype
```

Все типы данных наследуются от Object, это означает что:

```
Number.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype
```

И наконец, завершение цепочки:

```
Object.prototype.__proto__ === null
```

**Свойство prototype**

Это обычное свойство, ничем не отличающиеся от любых других свойств. За исключением двух особенностей:

> 1) Функции в JavaScript имеют свойство prototype. Оно по умолчанию
>   является объектом с единственным свойством constructor, которое
>   ссылается на саму функцию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> 2) Свойство prototype используется при создании новых объектов
>   оператором new.

Этот оператор делает следущее:

Создает пустой объект:

```
var instance = {};
```

Устанавливает **proto** этому объекту ссылкой на prototype функции-класса:

```
instance.__proto__ = FnClass.prototype;
```

Применяет функцию-класс к нашему новосозданному объекту:

```
constructorReturns = FnClass.apply(instance, arguments);
```

> т.е. исполняет функцию FnClass, передавая ей instance в качестве this и аргументы в виде массива arguments.

Возвращает экземпляр функции-класса, но если FnClass нам вернул обьект, тогда его:

```
return constructorReturns instanceof Object ? constructorReturns : instance;
```

Функцией-классом я называю функцию, к которой впоследствии ожидается применение оператора new. Такие функции принято именовать с заглавной буквы.